# PDO select display just one result even if there are more results in DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

its my first time using PDO in general i was working on one simple website, i finish my work but at final tests i find out that my function give back just one resut, dispite the fact there is more results for it in database. My code looks like this:

```
public function fetchByVinAxnmrs() {
    $success = false;
    try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_cases WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 35";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['date_created']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['axrmrs_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['case_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
            echo '<td><a class="iframe" href="detail.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&caseid='.$row['case_id'].'" class>details</a></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }catch(PDOExeption $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $con->errorInfo();
    }

    return $success; 
}
```

I have no idea if its something with PDO, or my SQL but in my eyes it should give back more results (max 35 ofc)

Any idea guys whats wrong?

Thanks for help for everybody who read it :)

Comment: I don't see any problem with the PDO. The only problem I see is that you have two `class` attributes in the `<a>` element.

Comment: What is output of `echo $stmt->rowCount()`?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there are multiple rows that match `$this->vin`?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing both `echo` in your function and `returning` data. I wonder how that will play out. I suggest that you change the block

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['date_created']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['axrmrs_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['case_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
            echo '<td><a class="iframe" href="detail.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&caseid='.$row['case_id'].'" class>details</a></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

to something like:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)){
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

Then you return the `$data` and then access that from `fetchByVinAxnmrs()`.